# input string was not in a correct format. in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class in aspx.cs

in that i have a function like below

```
public static String GetMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus)
        {
            if (maritalStatus == null)
                return "";
            String[] maritalStatuses = new String[] { "--", "Single", "Married", "Divorced", "Widowed" };

            return maritalStatuses[int.Parse(maritalStatus)];
        }
```

When this function is called I am getting

> input string was not in a correct format. Error

on the line

```
String[] maritalStatuses = new String[] { "--", "Single", "Married", "Divorced", "Widowed" };
```

What can be the reason.

Edited

```
String marital = GetMaritalStatus(02);
```

Comment: No, the error is bound to be on the `int.Parse` line - which will be due to `maritalStatus` not being a string representation of an integer. What is the value?

Comment: @jonSkeet thanks for the quick response..will check by debug..

Comment: @akemp - OP is passing `maritalStatus` and not `maritalStatuses`.

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried with out calling the function. So in my code no where this function is calling but still im getting the same error

Comment: Then you're probably not running the code you think you are.

Comment: How you call to this function? post the calling code please.

Comment: We need to know how the function is being called. You are trying to pass a marital status in string form, and want to get back the same in string form. I think this would not be the case. Are you supposed to find by INDEX, you might want to pass int paramter index.

Comment: @Muhammadldress yes..iam passing by index see my edited code

Comment: Shouldn't you call the function with `GetMaritalStatus("02");`?

Comment: @Magnetize sorry typing mistake its "02"

Comment: I think changing 02 to "02" would have solved this issue.

Comment: Hi all thanks for the helps..earlier i defined these functions inside separate class. Now i defined the function inside the same class from which it is called and problem is solved..

Comment: see answer in my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
String marital = GetMaritalStatus(02);
```

02 is integer but your function GetMaritalStatus takes argument as string

use the below code to call your function

```
String marital = GetMaritalStatus("02");
```

Comment: This is more like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen on

```
return maritalStatuses[int.Parse(maritalStatus)];
```

I think 'maritalStatus' isn't an int when you try your code which gives you your error.